# Optimizing a endless list of blocks?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm creating a game with ALOT of blocks. They are 48x48 pixels and virtually endless amouth, altho I will set some limit.

But how can I i optimize it, should I have one master list and for each Update decide which one to update and draw based on the game camera? No point in updating and drawing a block that is not viewable?

```
public override Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  blocks = new List<Block>();

  foreach(Block b in masterblocklist)
    if( screenRect.Contains(b.Rect) )
      blocks.Add(b);

  foreach(Block b in blocks)
    b.Update(gameTime);
}
```

So should I maintain a block list of blocks that are in the view or should i in both Update and Draw method check if block is in the screen rect, ifso Update and draw it? Or does it not matter at all? (Last solution requires to thru the list twice)

Comment: Culling as you described is one facet to increasing performance.  A technique you can use in addition to that is dirty-rect handling, where you only render blocks that havebeen modified, but that would depend on how rendering actually works in your engine.

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? Are you in an 3D or 2D scenario? I actually haven't really get the point of what exactly you want to achieve. Excluding blocks that are out of camera is called "culling" a good way to realize this is to use Quadtrees for 2D- and Octtrees for 3D-scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming side, I recommand **Parallel queries**:

```
public override Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  var parallelQuery = from b in masterblocklist.AsParallel()
                            where screenRect.Contains(b.Rect) 
                            select b;

 // Process result sequence in parallel
 parallelQuery.ForAll(p => p.Update(gameTime));
}
```

Comment: Beware of the concurrent access to some shared variables. I'm not sure this will works as simply as that